# Using square brackets inside an object: Unexpected Token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I'm leaving out a bunch of context, but I don't think a lot of it is necessary. I have a bunch of code leading up to an object with `prop` properties. I'm then setting up a `$scope.$watch` which is watching the object, and then, essentially, broadcasting `prop`—the name of the property, and `newValue[prop]`, the value of that property. It looks a bit like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){return object;}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    for (var prop in object) {
        if (newValue[prop] !== oldValue[prop]) {
            $scope.$broadcast('from-parent', {a: prop, b: newValue[prop]});
        }
    }
};
```

The broadcasted message `console.log()`'s out `Object {a: (the property's name), b: (the value of the property)}` as you would expect.

Strangely though, when I remove out the `a:` and `b:` keys, i.e.

```
$scope.$broadcast('from-parent', {prop, newValue[prop]});
```

I get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [` error.

Are you not allowed to refer to properties via brackets in objects? What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{prop, newValue[prop]}` won't create a property with the name from the `prop` variable, it just ends up being an invalid object initializer — not because of the `[]` (`{prop, "foo"}` would also have failed), but because object initializers don't work that way.

> ...the name of the property, and newValue[prop]

To give an object a property name from a variable, in ES5 you have to first create the object, *then* add the property:

```
var obj = {};
obj[prop] = newValue[prop];
$scope.$broadcast('from-parent', obj);
```

In ES6, you'll be able to use the new dynamic property name notation instead:

```
// REQUIRES ES6!
$scope.$broadcast('from-parent', {[prop]: newValue[prop]});
```